# cocoa touch: Waiting for a method to finish before continuing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

So I have an onclick event for a UIButton that needs to execute some code, but it can be pressed at anytime, so there is a chance that it is pressed while another method is still running.  Is there a way to block the click event until the specific method is finished?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this?  Post code and a description of the problem.

Comment: There's several ways that spring to mind without knowing much about your project. You could disable the button when other methods are started. Or, maybe a variable could be used as a flag to indicate whether it is safe to run the method. Other methods would set the value when they start and finish.

Comment: I can't post code as it contains company sensitive material, but essentially, I'm processing a video feed from the front camera in a sort of "calibration" mode, and there is a button on screen that the user can press to stop calibration, but if the method processing the video feed isn't let to finish, then certain UI elements on screen will have incorrect values. So basically, when the user clicks the button, I want to wait until the other method finished before I continue with the code in the rest of the onClick method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to block the click event until the specific method is finished?

Unless the "specific method" is running on another thread, that's already what happens. The run loop can't process input events while other code is running on the main thread.